# How to use function mapPartitionsWithIndex in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

the `mapPartitionsWithIndex` has a parameter `preservesPartitioning`, I don't know how to set it.

I did a test:

```
// partitionedRDD's type is RDD[(String, String)]
partitionedRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, iter) => {
                iter.map(_._1)
            }, args(2).toBoolean).saveAsTextFile(args(3))
```

whatever I set `preservesPartitioning` to `false` or `true`, the RDD partitions has not been changed. Why?

If I **wantn't changed** the partitions, what should I set value for `preservesPartitioning`?

Comment: If you don't want the partitioning to change don't provide a value. The default value is `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confused by preservesPartitioning meaning. By setting it to true, you are not saying to Spark 'please preserve the partions' you are telling it 'I have a function that preserves keys and the RDD is a pair RDD'.

From spark doc:

> `preservesPartitioning` indicates whether the input function preserves the partitioner, which should be `false` unless this is a pair RDD and the input function doesn't modify the keys.

In your case, you have a pair RDD and the function does not modify the key so the flag should be true.

Comment: In my case, whatever I set `preservesPartitioning` to `false` or `true`, it is no influence on the partitions. Does this means I can ignore this parameter? And how to use this parameter and what case I need notice value of this parameter? I mean what's the use of this parameter, it just to indecate whether the keys is modifyed or not?

Comment: By default, if you want it to be correct and ignore the parameter, always set it to false. This flag is for optimization purpose, when you dont modify the partition, Spark can do the operation more efficiently but it cant know if you dont tell.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it!